# how to pass multiple parameters to rake task

Tags: ruby, rake

I want to pass multiple parameter but I don't know the numbers. Such as model names. How do I pass those parameters into a rake task and how do I access those parameters inside the rake task.

Like, `$ rake test_rake_task[par1, par2, par3]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may try something like that:

```
rake test_rake_task SOME_PARAM=value1,value2,value3
```

And in rake task:

```
values = ENV['SOME_PARAM'].split(',')
```

Comment: can't i pass parameter this way ?? rake test_rake_task[par1,par2,par3] and access it ??

Comment: I've described the only way I know to pass parameters to rake task. It seams impossible to execute rake task with something like `rake test_rake_task[par1,par2,par3]`.

Comment: It is not impossible to execute rake task as such, Henry's answer below works to do just that.

Answer (score 73):

You can use `args.extras` to iterate over all the arguments without explicitly stating how many parameters you have.

Example:

```
desc "Bring it on, parameters!"
task :infinite_parameters do |task, args| 
    puts args.extras.count
    args.extras.each do |params|
        puts params
    end         
end
```

To run:

```
rake infinite_parameters['The','World','Is','Just','Awesome','Boomdeyada']
```

Output:

```
6
The
World
Is
Just
Awesome
Boomdeyada
```

Comment: By far the best way to pass unnamed parameters to a rake task without environment hacking.

Comment: Note this is true for more (or less) recent versions of rake.

Comment: This should definitely be the answer.

Comment: `undefined method count for nil:NilClass`, rake, version 0.9.6

Comment: Nakilon - what code did you run that gave you that error?

Comment: For me "The" doesn't get in extras. It needs to be appended from `args`

Answer (score 63):

Rake supports passing parameters directly to a task using an array, without using the ENV hack.

Define your task like this:

```
task :my_task, [:first_param, :second_param] do |t, args|
  puts args[:first_param]
  puts args[:second_param]
end
```

And call it like this:

```
rake my_task[Hello,World]
=> Hello
   World
```

[This article by Patrick Reagan on the Viget blog explains it nicely](http://www.viget.com/extend/protip-passing-parameters-to-your-rake-tasks/)

Comment: This did not answer the question. The OP says he does not know the number of arguments being passed.

Comment: @Henry Can you please describe the meaning/usage of `:needs` or provide documentation on this symbol?

Comment: @JJD If you are using the latest version of Ruby, I think :needs is deprecated. :needs indicated dependencies. Try something like 

`task :test, [:arg1, :arg2] => :environment do |t, args|
  #Code
end`

Comment: I think it did answer the question, but on my version of rake (11.2.2), it does not work with the space between the arguments. Everything works if I remove it.

Comment: FYI, You can't have spaces in between your arguments, or else it'll throw. That drove me batty for like 20 minutes. For example, you have to do `rake my_task[Hello,World]`

Answer (score 10):

**Found this example on this [blog post](http://itshouldbeuseful.wordpress.com/2011/11/07/passing-parameters-to-a-rake-task/)** and the syntax seems a bit cleaner.

For example, if you had a `say_hello` task, you could call it with any number of arguments, like so:

```
$ rake say_hello Earth Mars Venus
```

This is how it works:

```
task :say_hello do
  # ARGV contains the name of the rake task and all of the arguments.
  # Remove/shift the first element, i.e. the task name.
  ARGV.shift

  # Use the arguments
  puts 'Hello arguments:', ARGV

  # By default, rake considers each 'argument' to be the name of an actual task. 
  # It will try to invoke each one as a task.  By dynamically defining a dummy
  # task for every argument, we can prevent an exception from being thrown
  # when rake inevitably doesn't find a defined task with that name.
  ARGV.each do |arg|
    task arg.to_sym do ; end
  end

end
```

Comment: side effect: you won't be able to use other tasks with this one in one command

Answer (score 9):

Use args.values.

```
task :events, 1000.times.map { |i| "arg#{i}".to_sym } => :environment do |t, args|
  Foo.use(args.values)
end
```

Comment: Needed to use *args.to_hash.values*, and generating a thousand 4-characters arguments messed up *rake -T*, so I used *(?a..?e).to_a* instead.